# ¿Ayuda no puedo hacer update con Eloquent en laravel 5.6.25?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Hola estoy tratando de hacer un update en laravel, les dejo mi model y mi controller, ya incluso mostre en el log los valores y si estan correctos. Mi base de datos es Mysql.

Esto utilice en Ajax

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'PUT',
                url: 'posts/' + id,
                data: {
                    '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                    'id': $("#id_editar").val(),
                    'orden_de_compra': $('#orden_de_compra_editar').val(),
                    'cliente': $('#cliente_editar').val()
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('.errororden_de_compra').addClass('hidden');
                    $('.errorcliente').addClass('hidden');
```

Esta es mi funcion:

```
 public function update(Request $request, $pedido_id)
    {
        error_log($pedido_id);
               error_log($request->orden_de_compra);
               error_log($request->cliente);
           $array=array("pedido_id"=>$pedido_id);



              $post = Pedido::findOrFail($pedido_id);

           $post->cliente =  $request->cliente;

           $post->orden_de_compra = $request->orden_de_compra;
$post->save();

            return response()->json($array);

    }
```

y este mi modelo:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Pedido extends Model
{
   //evita la s para la tabla:  protected $table = 'table_name';


        protected $primaryKey = 'pedido_id';
        protected $fillable = ['orden_de_compra','cliente'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te saludo y te comento que lo deberías hacer de este modo

```
  $post = Pedido::findOrFail($pedido_id);
  $post->cliente =  $request->input('cliente');
  $post->orden_de_compra = $request->input('orden_de_compra');
  $post->save();
```

> Es decir debes usar el método input y por dentro entre comillas pasar
>   el nombre del input en tu HTML que contiene el valor que deseas
>   almacenar en tu BD

Aquí mas referencia en la documentación https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#accessing-the-request

Comment: Hola amigo no me funciono tu codigo, de hecho pase por ajax los parametros, ya actualize el codigo y agregue mi funcion de ajax, si envia los parametros porque los veo en el log, eso es lo raro pero no hace el update

Answer (score 0):

primero asegúrate de que el id recibido si sea el correcto.. eloquent cuenta con el metodo update, si los inputs de tu form son los mismos que los de tu bd, puedes hacer algo como esto

```
$post = Pedido::findOrFail($pedido_id);    
$post->update($request->all());
return ...
```

si inyectas la dependencia de la clase Pedido, y utilizas el mismo objeto en la ruta te ahorras la consulta

Answer (score 0):

Listo ya lo solucione agregue public $timestamps = false; a mi modelo, esto es debido a que no tengo la columna updated_at la cual espera eloquent por defecto.

Comment: sería bueno que al publicar una pregunta hagas la especificación de todos esos detalles saludos